# There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name HelloWorld

Tags: java, struts2

I am trying to run a simple struts 2 HelloWorld application ,when i run it ,says "There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name HelloWorld.Can somebody please help.

```
WARNING: Could not find action or result
There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name HelloWorld. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:189)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: show your struts-config.xml, might be not able to find action

Comment: have u mapped the action name in struts file ?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<struts>
   <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" /> 
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
 <package name="default"  namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="HelloWorld"  class="test.HelloWorld">
  <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>

 </action>
 
 </package>
</struts>

Answer (score 0):

->Check that the action is mapped into the struts file
->action name in jsp, in struts.xml and name of action class all are exactly same
->is action mapping in struts-config.xml is under some package, then include the package in the url (eg while submitting form, url must include name of package)

Comment: Here is the struts.xml and web.xml files

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<struts>
   <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" /> 
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
 <package name="default"  namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="HelloWorld"  class="test.HelloWorld">
  <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>

 </action>
 
 </package>
</struts>

Comment: <display-name>Struts2 Login</display-name>

 <filter>

  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
  </filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>

  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

 </filter-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

Answer (score 0):

More often that not when struts gets the action name wrong even when there's nothing wrong with struts.xml, the problem is that the tag lib definition is missing from the jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have made a mistake in the struts.xml file. There are several ways to configure this file; here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="helloWorld" class="controller.HelloWorld">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>

        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

If you do this in this way just make sure that you have to call action from the jsp by Action name only; You do not need to write `.action`: that will cause error.

This could answer your question.